# How to propagate an exception from ContinueWith to the calling context of an infinite loop task

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I have an infinite loop in a task. Under certain circumstances, this task throws an exception and terminates. Consider the following code snippet.

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int x = await FirstTask();
            window.Title = "FirstTask completed with " + x.ToString();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            textbox.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> FirstTask()
    {
        Task<int> secondTask;
        int result;

        secondTask = SecondTask();
        textbox.Text = "Awaiting SecondTask result";
        result = await secondTask;
        textbox.Text = result;

        secondTask.ContinueWith(async (Task t) =>
        {
             var thirdTask = ThirdTask();

             thirdTask.ContinueWith(
                async (m) =>
                     await Task.Run(() =>
                     {
                        throw thirdTask.Exception.InnerException;
                     }),
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

        return 5;
    }

    public async Task<int> SecondTask()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1500);
        return 8;
    }

    public async Task ThirdTask()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);

            throw new ArgumentException("thirdException");
        }
    }
```

My problems lies in the inability to propagate the exception thrown from ThirdTask to the Button_Click event. Obviously, awaiting it is not an options, since it is an ongoing infinite operation (this is only simplified to fail quickly). I have, however, no problem with awaiting the "short" task which re-throws the exception, if it is only triggered once the ThirdTask fails. Note that I'm not interested in the doings of the ThirdTask unless it fails, that is while I'm able to await the FirstTask in the event handler.

Experimenting showed that even the most simple example doesn't propagate the exception from the ContinueWith block.

```
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Task task = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); });
            task.ContinueWith( (t) => { throw new ArgumentException("test"); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);          
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            textbox.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

So, how do I propagate an exception from ContinueWith to the calling context, given that the task that throws it has an infinite loop, which prevents me from awaiting it?

The problem I'm trying to solve is two-fold:
First, I need to initialize a resource (FirstTask), in order to do that, I first need to fetch it (SecondTask) and then to begin a process with it (ThirdTask), finally, the initialization of the resource (FirstTask) returns a value indicating the state of the resource, which doesn't depend on the process (ThirdTask). The process (ThirdTask) repeatedly invokes another task (in this case Task.Delay) and performs some work on it, but it can fail. In that case, it throws an exception which needs to be handled.

The second part is the general case of the second code example, of how to throw an exception from ContinueWith to be handled by the calling context.

Comment: Actually, awaiting *is* the solution and the infinite loop doesn't affect anything. An exception *will* break the loop so awaiting the task returned from `ContinueWith` will catch the exception. In fact, you don't even need `ContinueWith`, you could `await ThirdTask()` inside a proper excetion handling block. `await` will also unwrap the thrown exception so you would get back the initial `ArgumentException`

Comment: Why the complicated code and `ContinueWith`? What actual problem were you trying to solve? `await SecondTask();await ThirdTask();` should be enough, both to start `ThirdTask()` after `SecondTask()` *and* propagate any exceptions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos wouldn't await ThirdTask block the calling method there until the ThirdTask completes (in my case ultimately the button click handler)? If no exception is thrown, that would be forever, which is not desired. The exception should not regularly happen, but I should be able to handle it if it occurs. The complicated code is simplified to emphasize the problem. Every task does something, so this is just a outline of the program structure.

Comment: No. `await` doesn't block, that's the whole point. It **awaits* for a Task to finish by releasing the current thread. When that other task completes, it retrieves the result (or exception) and continues in its original context - in desktop applications, that's the original (UI) thread. If an exception was thrown by the task, it's rethrown by await. Are you confusing the `await` keyword with the `.Wait()` method?

Comment: please check out the edit I made to the code (made the button handle actually use the result of FirstTask). What I meant by "blocking" in my previous comment is that that particular line of code will never be executed if ThirdTask is an infinite loop and doesn't throw exceptions, i.e. the ThirdTask never completes and neither does the FirstTask. Even though FirstTask isn't supposed to depend on ThirdTask (it just starts it), the result will never be ready. If you have a better solution how to design this, please propose it.

Comment: I think you should describe the *actual* problem you are trying to solve, not the attempted solution. If you wanted to perform long-running background processing, you could use any number of techniques instead of an infinite loop. If you have a producer/consumer scenario, you could use eg an ActionBlock. An infinite loop is almost the opposite of asynchronous processing

Comment: @user3209815 If you want the method to return a result successfully then it can't *later* become a faulted task.  You need it to *either* complete successfully *or* fail.  You can do whichever you want, just not both.  You shouldn't be calling the second and third operations from the first if you want the first method to expose the results of both of them; have the click handler call both directly if you really need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> given that the task that throws it has an infinite loop, which prevents me from awaiting it?

That in no way prevents you from awaiting it.  The [easiest] way to handle the case that it throws an exception is specifically to `await` it.

You can simply implement the method as such:

```
public async Task FirstTask()
{
    Task<int> secondTask = SecondTask();
    textbox.Text = "Awaiting SecondTask result";
    textbox.Text = await secondTask;
    await ThirdTask();
}
```

If the click handler needs to both update a texbox with the results of the second operation and update the UI if the third fails, then you need to not wrap both of those operations in `FirstTask` and call them directly from the click handler:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textbox.Text = "Awaiting SecondTask result";
        int x = await SecondTask();
        window.Title = "SecondTask completed with " + x.ToString();
        await ThirdTask();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        textbox.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```